# Prove a sequence is convergent and find the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence as below 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array} {l}
x_1=1\\
x_{n+1}=3-\frac{x_n+2}{2^{x_n}}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Prove that the sequence converges to a limit, and find the limit?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you already a guess for the limit? Hint: Recurrence relations are often solved via induction (on two steps).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The function $$f(x) = (3-x)2^x - (x+2)$$ is positive on $[0,2)$ 
and $f(2)=0$.

The function $g(x) = x+2-2^x$ is positive on $[0,2)$ and $g(2)=0$.

This makes the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ increasing and upper bounded by $2$. Its limit $\ell$ therefore lies in $(1,2]$, and satisfies $f(\ell) = 0$, so $\ell = 2$